# How to make a website with two language for front end using TYPO3 v6.2

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I need to create a website with two languages one with English and  German. I'm not aware of TYPO3 scripts.
As I studied different references I saw [this](http://www.typo3manual.se/module-manuals/language-layers-typo3-version-6/) one and tried to work out.
But I'm not able to use it because their is no language bar in top of my TYPO3 back end. Also when i tried to add language in drop down of edit page and add content page it shows only 'Default' in the list.

How can make a website with different language switching in front end?
thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add the 2 languages in your rootpage?

Comment: @nbar . Am also having the same problem. When I tried to add multiple languages in root it shows only Default in drop down box. I already added German using language menu and update from repository. backend shows diffrerent languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *"List"*-Module (on the left) is your friend:

chose the list module and afterwards your *rootpage* in the pagetree (PID = 0).
In the content section in the right upper bar you can *"create a new record"*.

Chose *"Website language"* and fill in the wanted properties and values...

Afterwards you will find the dropdown to create a page translation in the newly added language...

Comment: Actually I found the ans . I was unaware of adding language to "PID=0" I was trying with "root page" of file tree. Any way the ans will be helpful for coming people have same issue. thank you.